# What is wrong with this mail to link?

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with a mail to link when I try to put in a body. what is wrong?

```
function mailtogametag(argument) {
    window.location.href = "mailto:" + "" + "?subject=" + "" + "&body="
       newPostKey + "%20Please note the dash is required!";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems that you're missing a '+' near `newPostKey`. Also `argument` is never used.

Comment: Please do not post minified code! Edited.

Comment: What is `newPostKey` I don't see it defined and what is the purpose of `argument` I don't see it being used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `+` sign between `"&body="` and `newPostKey` :

```
..+ "?subject=" + "" + "&body=" + newPostKey +  "%20Please no...
________________________________^
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you support es6 (or using babel) then maybe [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can make it a little bit easier for you next time

```
function mailtogametag (argument) {
    window.location.href = `mailto:${''}?subject=${''}&body=${newPostKey}%20Please note the dash is required!`;
}
```